# how to remove all slides from jquery cycle 2 slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle2

I want to remove all slides from JQuery 2 cycle slider, in the [`API`](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/) it says to remove a specific slide you can run this code:

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('remove', 1);
```

But how can I remove all?

Comment: Can't you do `$('.cycle-slideshow').find('.cycle-slide').remove();`

Comment: I could but I think it messes it up when I want to add slides again

Comment: Well in that case you I guess you could simply call `remove` in a loop from `0` to `slideCount`. You should be able to get `slideCount` from the `hash`. The code would look something like `for(var i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) { $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('remove', i); }`

Comment: I tried that too but it doesn't remove the slide called .cycle-sentinel, it's the one it duplicate for the continuous loop I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a loop to remove all slides. Call remove in a loop from `0` to `slideCount`:

```
// get the number of slides
var numSlides = $('.cycle-slideshow').data('cycle.opts').slideCount;
for(var slide = 0; slide < numSlides; slide++) {
  $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('remove', slide);
  // if the elements are not removed from the DOM you could also
  // try call $('.cycle-slideshow .cycle-slide').eq(slide).remove(); here
}
// reinitialize the plugin
$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('reinit');
```

Comment: this is right but you need to reninitate the slider too.

Comment: @user1937021 - A question, was you able to achive this without using `$('.cycle-slideshow .cycle-slide').eq(slide).remove();`?